# How can I sniff local traffic

Tags: windows, sniffer

I have WAR app A that calls app B. I want to sniff traffic between them. How can I do it? OS: Windows

Answer (score -2):

Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) is a useful tool for sniffing network packets.  I had this kind of problem yesterday (although it was between a windows app and a device on the network).  I had never used Wireshark before then, but I was able to use it and read through the data in a matter of minutes.  I haven't tried it between two apps on the same machine, however.

Comment: Wireshark can't capture local windows traffic - http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/200706/msg00050.html